# Calculate the dimension of the eigenspace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> $A= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 & 0\\  4 &  4 & 0\\  2 &  1 & 2
> \end{pmatrix}$ is the matrix.
>
> The tripple eigenvalue is $\lambda=2$
>
> The eigenspace is $E_{A}(2)= \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} x\\ 
> -2x\\  z \end{pmatrix} \mid x,z \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$
>
> What's the dimension of the eigenspace?

I think in order to answer that we first need the basis of the eigenspace:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
x\\ 
-2x\\ 
z
\end{pmatrix}= x\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
-2\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}+z\begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
0\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix}$$

So basis $B= 
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
-2\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
0\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix}$

We have $2$ vectors here thus the dimension of the eigenspace is $2$?

---

Please can you tell me if this is done correctly?

Comment: Assuming your numerical working is correct, then yes! You can also see it directly from noting that in $E_A (2)$ you've only got two variables which you can move independently from one another

Comment: I checked your computation of the equation of your eigenspace and this one is also correct. If you do not need a basis, but only the dimension: check TheMathsGeek's comment. In case you need a basis: way to go :)

Comment: @TheMathsGeek Great, glad to hear that! Just one more question, the way I have written the basis seems a bit weird. How would a nice / correct notation of it look?

Comment: @Student Thank you! :)

Comment: The usual notation is something like $$B = \{(1,-2,0)^T,(0,0,1)^T\}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to find particular eigenvectors if all you want is the *dimension* of the eigenspace.

The eigenspace is the null space of $A-\lambda I$, so just find the rank of that matrix (say, by Gaussian elimination, but possibly only into non-reduced row echelon form) and subtract it from $3$ per the rank-nullity theorem.

Comment: Oh I haven't read of this before, this will surely save me a lot time, and probably it's also not as error-prone as the usual way calculating the eigenvalues, I often did mistakes :P