# True or false? The matrix $M$ is not diagonalisable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Given is matrix $M=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 & 0\\  4 &  4 & 0\\  2 &  1
> & 2 \end{pmatrix}$
>
> Its characteristic polynomial is
>   $-\alpha^{3}+6\alpha^{2}-12\alpha+8=0$
>
> The tripple eigenvalue is $\alpha=2$

These are given and I'm supposed to say if this matrix is diagonalisable or not.

I think from all these given things, it should be possible to directly say if it's true or not, well I hope so.

But this task is strange because I don't know if an eigenvalue counts as $3$ eigenvalues if you get the same eigenvalue $3$ times. That's why I cannot say from these given things if it's true or false.

**So this eigenvalue counts as $1$ eigenvalue or really $3$?**

Is it possible to answer that question with only these given things or I have to determine the eigenspace (then it would be easy to answer but why the effort if it could be easier)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\textbf{General case: }$ In order to know if a matrix is diagonizable, you should find its characteristic polynomial, then find all zeros of this polynomial and as a last step check for each eigenvalue if its algebraic multiplicity (the number of times the eigenvalue is a zero of the characteristic polynomial) matches the geometric multiplicity (the dimension of the corresponding eigenspace). This can become a very long computation in the general case.

$\textbf{Your Case: }$ However, you are lucky: the question states that there is only one zero to the characteristic polynomial (since the degree of this polynomial is $3$ and $\lambda = 2$ has multiplicity $3$ in this polynomial), so all you have to do is find a basis corresponding to the eigenspace of the unique eigenvalue $\lambda = 2$.

If you would find that the dimension of the eigenspace is strictly less than $3$, your matrix is not diagonizable. If the dimension is $3$, then you have that the matrix is diagonizable.

$\textbf{EDIT: }$ In your case, it will not be diagonizable, since if you want to find the basis of the eigenspace, you end up with the matrix from one of your former questions: [Calculate the dimension of the eigenspace](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2179368/calculate-the-dimension-of-the-eigenspace), and you already know the dimension of that eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda =2$ of that matrix.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

You matrix is diagonalizable iff $\;x-2\;$ is its minimal polynomial, and this happens iff $\;M-2I=0\;$ ....

Comment: If get three times the same eigenvalue, does it count as three eigenvalues? In this example I get three times $\alpha=2$ as eigenvalue. Now I have $1$ eigenvalue or $3$?

Comment: You have one eigenvalue with algebraic multeplicity 3, i.e. is the triple solution of your equation of degree three. This information alone is not enough to say if your matrix is diagonalizable. For the matrix to be diagonalizable you need the geometric multeplicity of your eigenvalue to be equal to the algebraic one.

Comment: @c Yes, you can count it that way though that won't help you by itself to decide whether the matrix is diagonlaizable or not. A matrix is diagonalizable iff for every eigenvalue, its algebraic multiplicity = its geometric multiplicity, and this last is simply the dimension of hte corresponding eigenspace, and this means the matrix's minimal polynomial is the product of **different** linear factors.

Answer (score 2):

Can you find $3$ linearly independent eigenvectors all having $2$ as an eigenvalue? In that case, $2$ will count as a triple eigenvalue. This is the interpretation that comes from asking what diagonalisation *is*, namely finding a basis of $\Bbb R^3$ consisting of eigenvectors to your transformation, and then expressing the transformation in that basis. If there is a triple root to the characteristic polynomial, then it must contribute three dimensions to this basis, or else the transformation is not diagonalisable (there will not be enough eigenvalues to cover the entire space that way).